# Get img tags from an xml

Tags: java, android, xml, pattern-matching

I have the following code that gets the img tags urls from an XML which is working correctly:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(xmlString);
while (m.find())
    imagesURLs.add(m.group(1));
```

My xml looks like the following:

```
<item>
    <desc>
       txt txt txt txt <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> txt txt
       <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> ...
    </desc>
</item>
<item>
    <desc>
       txt txt txt txt <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"> txt txt
       <img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png"><img src="htttp://mysite.com/images/img.png">
    </desc>
</item>
```

I want to modify the code to only get the first img tag url from each desc tag.

Comment: use a proper xml parser

Comment: I have that in other places when I need all the data in the xml. but, not when I only needs the images on the home pages where I want to let them play one by one behind the home buttons.

Comment: So if you already have a proper XML parser in your codebase, why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: which one of them is faster?

Comment: I have a lot of processing on my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a regex to figure this out (Which is a very **POOR** way to do this...) You should actually parse the xml using some Xml parsing library as provided by java. Like XmlPullParser.